# Ports and protocol used by Maven to download dependencies in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ports

I'm on an enterprise working with eclipse as a programmer, and I have a project that works perfect at home. However, when I try to compile the pom.xml at work it says: "Failure to transfer org.apache.maven" and "connect time out". 
I think it is because the network firewall in the enterprise is very restrictive with the use of ports, possibly blocking the acces. Does anyone know which ports and protocol does maven use to configure itself and do the installation? Can those ports be manually changed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Always read the documentation. There isn't a specific protocol to maven. Just configure the proxy settings: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify the url port you can do something like this in `settings.xml`:

```
 <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>repoId</id>
          <url>http://url:port/remains</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

And to [use a proxy in maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html), you can also add modify your `settings.xml`:

```
<settings>
  .
  .
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  .
  .
</settings>
```

Adapt as needed.

Comment: I think I need to use the proxy. However, I am not sure about the information I need to have one running, I mean, I never used one, can it be on my computer? How can the proxy pass the security of the ports, if natively I can't reach those ports? Thanks!

Comment: Check the config of your PC (either defined in your browser, or on your laptop config, which is OS dependant in that case), otherwise ask your helpdesk, or a colleague..etc For the proxy, you would need to see its config, not sure you'd be allowed though

Comment: I see, I would need to ask to my net security manager for the use of the proxy and he would tell me the proxy session data to login, and bypass the port blockings. Am I right?

Comment: Basically you need to ask for the settings used to be allowed by the proxy (not bypassing it!), as written above: the protocol (http or htpps or both), the hostname and the port (optionally the login/password, though most of the time yours should work).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll ask the info and set it it up!

Answer (score 2):

```
..\apache-maven-*.*.*\conf\settings.xml
```

mirrors add

```
   <mirror>
        <id>nexus-aliyun</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <name>Nexus aliyun</name>
        <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
```

Comment: There is no point in adding another mirror, which is perhaps blocked by the very same firewall rules...